# How to use the whole SVG with a <use> tag?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG file freshly exported from Figma.

1. I don't want to inline it because it's used on multiple places.
2. I can't specify it as `<img src="...">` because I need to style its parts.

So, I tried to include it like this:

```xml
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="http://example.com/myshape.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

But it doesn't work. MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use):

> The `<use>` element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else.

It takes *nodes* from the document. With SVG sprites, you have `<symbol>` tags with `id` attributes and you reference them with `<use>` by adding `xlink:href="mysprite.svg#symbolid"`. However, here I need to use the whole document, I.E. the root node. Is there a way to do that?

It would also be great if I don't have to edit the source SVG file, as it's uploaded via an admin panel by the user. It's just a file exported from any vector graphics program.

Comment: Give the root node an id and point the use to that id

Comment: That kind of works. The uploaded SVG file must be edited, though, and I need to specify the `viewBox` attribute in my markup, and I can't know what that value should be since it's a file uploaded by the user. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4):

For now (as of 2023/11) you need to add an #id to the root of your target SVG and refer it as a "fragment identifier":

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->
<svg id="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg#icon"></use>
```

[SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-UseElement) (when implemented in browsers) will allow to reference another SVG file without any [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment):

> New in SVG 2: An `href` without a fragment allows an entire SVG document to be referenced without having to ensure that it has an ID on its root element.

Future (there will be no need to define `id="..."` on the `svg`):

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg"></use>
```

SVG 2 seems to be in the process of development in major browsers (see [this Chrome feature](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408) and specifically this Chromium issue: [Issue 366545: [SVG2] Allow  to reference entire files](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366545)).