# How to render an external SVG file with the <use> tag?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I am trying to do something which I thought was a very simple task, but I just can't make it work. I have exactly copied about 8 other examples I found online, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215009/how-to-reference-external-svg-file-in-svg-correctly), but to no avail.

I am actually working on a React project, but to make the example easier, let's reduce the situation to just this:

I have a folder called *svg* containing *svg.html* and *icon.svg*.

svg.html contains:

```html
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<svg>  
<use href="icon.svg" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

icon.svg contains:

```html
<svg width="19" height="18" viewBox="0 0 19 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M16.5 0H2.5C1.4 0 0.5 0.9 0.5 2V16C0.5 17.1 1.4 18 2.5 18H16.5C17.6 18 18.5 17.1 18.5 16V2C18.5 0.9 17.6 0 16.5 0ZM2.5 16V2H8.5V16H2.5ZM16.5 16H10.5V9H16.5V16ZM16.5 7H10.5V2H16.5V7Z" fill="#9F9E99"/>
</svg>
```

When I run the html, simply nothing at all is displayed. What I want to happen, is for the icon.svg to be displayed in the html.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here: https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg

Comment: I specifically want to use the <svg> tag, because I want to the color to change on hover.

Comment: Currently you can't reference a complete svg. But it might be implemented in the future according to SVG 2 draft. See also [How to use the whole SVG with a <use> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452106/how-to-use-the-whole-svg-with-a-use-tag)

Comment: Search for the load-file web component, it loads svg files also

Comment: @herrstrietzel So not a complete SVG, but would this work if I had multiple svg drawings in icon.svg, and then referenced to only one of them by ID? That would serve the purpose, but I didn't get that done either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store multiple icon assets in an external svg file.

#### Create an icon asset file using `<symbol>` elements

A common practice is to wrap your icons in a `<symbol>` elements.

It is crucial to give all your icons/symbols a **unique ID**.

Now you can reference each icon like so:

```
<svg>  
  <use href="icon.svg#symbolID" />
</svg>
```

#### Overriding icon styles

Besides, you should **keep your icon styles/style attributes as neutral as possible** – so remove `fill` or `style` attributes – otherwise style overriding (e.g. inheriting colors from text or changing fills on hover) gets more complicated.

```css
body{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.icn-svg{
  height:1em;
  width:auto;
  fill:currentColor;
}

.icn-svg-square{
  height:1em;
  width:1em;
}
```

```html
<p style="color:red">
  <svg class="icn-svg" viewBox="0 0 19 18">
    <use href="#customIcon" /> 
  </svg>
  Custom icom
</p>

<p style="color:green">
  <svg class="icn-svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <use href="#icon-chess-pawn" /> 
  </svg>
  fontAwesome icon proportional
</p>

<p style="color:purple">
  <svg class="icn-svg icn-svg-square" >
    <use href="#icon-calendar" /> 
  </svg>
  fontAwesome icon (square)
</p>


<!-- external icion.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:0;height:0;">
  <symbol id="customIcon" viewBox="0 0 19 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M16.5 0H2.5C1.4 0 0.5 0.9 0.5 2V16C0.5 17.1 1.4 18 2.5 18H16.5C17.6 18 18.5 17.1 18.5 16V2C18.5 0.9 17.6 0 16.5 0ZM2.5 16V2H8.5V16H2.5ZM16.5 16H10.5V9H16.5V16ZM16.5 7H10.5V2H16.5V7Z" />
  </symbol>
  
  <symbol class="icon icon-chess-pawn" id="icon-chess-pawn" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <path d="M296 463.1H23.1c-13.25 0-23.1 10.75-23.1 24s10.75 24 23.1 24h272c13.25 0 23.1-10.75 23.1-23.1S309.3 463.1 296 463.1zM55.1 287.1L80 287.1v29.5c0 40.25-3.5 81.25-23.38 114.5h53.5C125.1 394.1 128 354.6 128 317.5v-29.5h64v29.5c0 37.13 2.875 77.5 17.88 114.5h53.5C243.5 398.7 240 357.7 240 317.5V287.1l24-.0001C277.3 287.1 288 277.3 288 263.1c0-13.25-10.75-24-23.1-24H241c23.75-21.88 38.1-53.12 38.1-87.1c0-9.393-1.106-19.05-3.451-28.86C272.3 105.4 244.9 32 159.1 32C93.75 32 40 85.75 40 151.1c0 34.88 15.12 66.12 39 88H55.1C42.75 239.1 32 250.7 32 263.1C32 277.3 42.75 287.1 55.1 287.1zM160 79.1c39.75 0 72 32.25 72 72S199.8 223.1 160 223.1S88 191.7 88 151.1S120.2 79.1 160 79.1z"></path>
  </symbol>

  <symbol class="icon icon-calendar" id="icon-calendar" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
    <path d="M152 64H296V24C296 10.75 306.7 0 320 0C333.3 0 344 10.75 344 24V64H384C419.3 64 448 92.65 448 128V448C448 483.3 419.3 512 384 512H64C28.65 512 0 483.3 0 448V128C0 92.65 28.65 64 64 64H104V24C104 10.75 114.7 0 128 0C141.3 0 152 10.75 152 24V64zM48 448C48 456.8 55.16 464 64 464H384C392.8 464 400 456.8 400 448V192H48V448z" />
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

We can't use external svgs in SO snippets. Just replace the inline references to something like `icons.svg#customIcon` when running on local server.

[Plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/piRPgwR531Yd7ybz?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

In the above snippet, all fill attributes are removed.
This way we can easily inherit text colors via `fill: currentColor` in a css rule like this:

```
.icn-svg{
  height:1em;
  width:auto;
  fill:currentColor;
}
```

#### Symbols with individual `viewBox` settings

Only needed, if you're dealing with different icon aspect ratios – if all icons are drawn relative to a square (like) viewBox – you can set the icons with and height directly.

For a "proportional" icon layout – define an appropriate `viewBox` for each icon `<symbol>` element and copy these values for the parent `<svg>` elemnts containing your `<use>` reference element.

#### External icon svgs should be hosted on same domain

Major browsers are very strict – even if your icon svg is hosted on a **cdn** allowing cross origin access, it won't work, unless you're fetching and inlining the file first.

As commented by **Danny '365CSI' Engelman** you could use his [load-file native web component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd).

You might also use keyamoon's ["svgxuse" helper script](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse).

Important: you can only fetch/inject external svg icons if they are hosted on servers **allowing cross origin access!** (e.g image sharing platforms like svgshare don't send a suitable CORS header).

#### Alternative: use a existing icon library

Seriously, creating custom icons is great but also requires some research and quite a lot of testing/debugging.

So **if** you're not overly excited about svg, you should better opt for an existing icon library like fontAwesome, material icons ... test icomoon, fontello included libraries/export functions (the latter ones can also export svg files) ... the list goes on and on.

The point is: creating your own custom icon library is usually not very trivial – especially mixing icons from different sources is quite tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I ran your code, but only the three coloured texts are shown, not the SVG's. Are they shown when you try it? I'm just running it from my VS Code editor, not on any server (yet). Does that, as you say, not allow cross origin acces?

Comment: Yes it wont't work when accessing the html as a file. You need a server (e.g VS Code's live server)